# Resultset giving only one row as result even there are many rows

Tags: spring-jdbc, apache-stringutils

Here is my query i have done using jdbc.webshopProducts is the Map.

```
StringBuilder queryString=new StringBuilder();
            queryString.append(" select cpm.name,cpm.catalogueprice,cpm.catalogueno ");
            queryString.append(" from customer_product_master cpm ");
            queryString.append(" where cpm.catalogueno in (?) ");
            stmt=con.prepareStatement(queryString.toString());
            stmt.setString(1,StringUtils.join(webshopProducts.keySet(),','));
rs=stmt.executeQuery();
            webshopProductList=new ArrayList<WebshopProductVO>();
            while(rs.next()){
                WebshopProductVO webshopProduct=new WebshopProductVO();
                webshopProduct.setArticleno(rs.getInt("catalogueno"));
                webshopProduct.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                webshopProduct.setPrice(rs.getFloat("catalogueprice"));
                webshopProduct.setQuantity(webshopProducts.get(rs.getInt("catalogueno")));
                webshopProduct.setSum(rs.getFloat("catalogueprice")*webshopProducts.get(rs.getInt("catalogueno")));
                webshopProductList.add(webshopProduct);
            }
```

I have used StringUtils.join(webshopProducts.keySet(),',') to generate a comma seperated list of integers.The problem i am facing is when there is more than one value in the map only one WebshopProductVO is being added to the webshopProductList even though there are many ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure , which database you are using. But you should be needing the number of ? equals to number of values youar passing.

suppose you have two values for in clause , then it should be :-

```
where cpm.catalogueno in (?,?)
```

and you should be setting same number of string.

```
  stmt.setString(1,"somevalue");
  stmt.setString(2,"somevalue2");
```

You need to write teh loop on keyset on both statments to append the ? and setting the string parameter